# Threading in python to build wordcloud

Tags: python, multithreading

I am building a simple word frequency counter application in python. The document has close to 1.6 million words. I divide the work (sentences) equally among threads. Ideally one would except the running time to decrease as number of threads increase (till some threshold) but this doesn't seems to be the case in my testing. Single thread is considerably faster than multithreaded implementation every time for some reason. I was earlier using locks to write into a global hash table but I found that to be way inefficient for multithreaded environment (at least 2-3 times slower). Then I started writing into individual hash tables for each thread and merging them in the end. The single threaded approach now takes time ~4.5 seconds but the multithreaded way is at least a second or two slower. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong maybe?

Comment: 1.6M words probably doesn't warrant the effort of multitasking; computers are fast. Search for "Python GIL" for the infamous Global Interpreter Lock and why multithreading provides little to negative improvement for a class of tasks.

Comment: Out of curiousity, I just counted 1.64M words with `collections.Counter` on a dippy laptop in  2 short lines of code in 244ms. You really don't need threading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is called [Global Interpreter Lock](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf). This mechanism makes it possible for only one thread to be executed at any given time.

You may notice another anomaly, the more cores you have, slower you code will run. If all threads are on the single core, OS can schedule their execution without contention for GIL, however if threads are split between multiple cores than there will be contention for the GIL which can be very noticeable.

If you wish to do parallel processing, than you should consider approach with [multiple processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), not threads, that is the preferred approach in python.

You could still use threads for blocking IO operations, although it's better to write non-blocking code in this scenario, [twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is popular framework for this.